# Locally connecting to AWS RDS on Dbeaver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I deployed my Spring Boot server using EC2 and RDS(MySQL).

How the security group is set up is this:

**EC2**

- inbound rules from certain IPs(for security)
- outbound open for all traffic

**RDS**

- inbound rule only allowing EC2 access
- outbound open for all traffic

They are in the same VPC and AZ.

--------Problem--------

When I run my server in EC2, it connects to RDS, but when I try to access RDS with DBeaver from my Mac, I'm always getting:

```
Connection Timed Out.
Communications Link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
The driver has no received any packets from the server.
Connection Timed Out.
```

--------What I tried--------

1. Allowing traffic from My IP on RDS security group
2. Allowing MySQL/Aurora from My IP on EC2 security group
3. Both of the above
4. Allowing all incoming traffic

But none of the above is working.
It's a development environment but I still want to keep my database safe as one of my friend's company database got attacked recently..


Is there a way to safely access the database on DBeaver(on my Mac) without opening up traffic more?

**UPDATE**

[image: So I can successfully connect to my EC2 through SSH]

So I can successfully connect to my EC2 through SSH

However I can't seem to connect to my RDS still..
[image]

Comment: If your RDS is in the private subnet, you will not be able to access it directly from your Mac. You need to create a bastion host to access RDS in private subnet.

Can you confirm if your RDS is in a private subnet or public subnet ?

Comment: it is deployed in a private subnet @MANISH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me from a first glance that you're deployed RDS instance in the private subnet. In this case your RDS instance will not be accessible from public.

There are a number of options you might consider in this case:

1. Redeploy RDS instance in public subnet (not recomended due security reasons).
2. Set up an SSH tunnel in DBeaver, so all your traffic go through the EC2 instance you've already configured. In this case you just need to put credentials in SSH tab of DBeaver (see screenshot).
3. Finally, you can manually forward port through the EC2 instance to your RDS instance. Let me know if you want me to show you an example.

[image]

Comment: what would be the username and password for my ec2? @Ilya Khrustalev

Comment: So I put 
Host/IP: ec2 public IPv4
User Name: since i'm running ubuntu -> ubuntu
Private Key: pem key for ssh access

when i test tunnel configuration, I get a "Connected!" message, but when I try
"Test Connection...." for the database, I still get the same error

Comment: Inseok, it looks like you did everything correct. The idea is to route your connection through the EC2 instance which has access to RDS instance. If you're still receiving Timeout error, I would suggest checking database credentials on Main tab. Host and Port are most likely can be wrong.

Comment: wow thank you so much! i got it connected!